# OpenAI-gym how to implement a timer for a certain action in step()

Tags: python, pygame, openai-gym

One of the actions I want the agent to do needs to have a delay between every action. For context, in pygame I have the following code for shooting a bullet:

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    # ready to fire when 600 ms have passed.
    if current_time - previous_time > 600:
        previous_time = current_time
        bullets.append([x + 25, y + 24])
```

I've set a timer to prevent bullet spamming, how would I construct this to work with the step() method? My other actions are moving up, down, left, right.

This is my first time creating a project with OpenAI-gym so I'm not sure what the capabilities of the toolkit are, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever method of tracking time you like (other than `pygame.time.get_ticks()` I suppose), and use a similar approach as in that `pygame` code. You'd want to store `previous_time` as a member of the environment instead of just a local variable, because you want it to persist across function calls.

It's not easy to actually prevent your Reinforcement Learning agent (assuming you're using gym for RL) from selecting the fire action altogether, but you can simply implement the `step()` function in such a way that the agent does not do anything at all if they select the fire action too quickly.

As for measuring time, you could measure wall clock time, but then the power of your CPU is going to influence how often your agent is allowed to shoot (it might be able to shoot a new bullet every step on very old hardware, but only be allowed to shoot one bullet every 100 steps on powerful hardware), that's probably a bad idea. Instead, I'd recommend measuring "time" simply by counting the `step()` calls. For example, using only the code from your question above, the `step()` function could look like:

```
def step(action):
    self.step_counter += 1

    # other step() code here

    if action == FIRE:
        if self.step_counter - self.previous_time > 10:    # or any other number
            self.previous_time = self.step_counter
            bullets.append([x + 25, y + 24])

    # other step() code here
```

Don't forget that you'll also want to reset your newly added member variables in `reset()`:

```
def reset():
    self.step_counter = 0
    self.previous_time = -100   # some negative number such that your agent can fire at start
    # other reset() code here
```

Comment: Damn, thanks once again for your time. Considering how much you've already helped I felt bad to ask you again directly. It seems like my render() and reset() methods are fine, just having problems with how I'd set valid actions and return the actions in the step() part. Could I send you my code to look over and see if I've formatted it correctly?

Comment: @Rokas98765 Sure. Most RL agents using gym only ask environments what the action space is once, before training starts, and they always select actions from that space. So, it's not really common to have state-dependent legal action sets. That's why I recommended simply accepting any action in `step()`, but ignoring it if it's not allowed yet. Then the agent has to learn for itself when actions are useless (or simply end up wasting some time executing actions that don't do anything). Note that `step()` normally doesn't return actions.